# Bathtub/showerhead leak, short water pipe

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

I bought a new home recently and found that the water in the bathroom tub/shower comes out of both the showerhead and tub spout (when the diverter is "off").

I removed the spout to see if there was anything clogged inside.  As I was removing it, I noticed that there was some caulk/glue on the base of the spout where it met the wall tiles.  Turns out the spout wasn't clogged, so I put it back on for now.  To my dismay, water now sprays out of the now-unsealed spout base when the shower is on.

I have a few questions:

1) It seems like the water output pipe coming from the wall is much shorter and looks different compared to the pictures I've seen online.  In all the pictures I've seen, the water pipe is a thin copper   My pipe extends approximately 1 inch from the wall (see pictures)  Is this normal?  And if not, what should I install to extend the pipe?

2) What is causing the initial problem of having water come out of both the showerhead and the spout? Will replacing the spout do the job?  Is the short water pipe a concern?

3) Do I need to put some sort of sealant/caulk around the spout base like it had before?

Thank you.

[image: water pipe]
[image: closeup]

Comment: use a razor to shave the wall washer off. Than try to re-install the spout. If you feel a positive fitment and it seems rigid, check for proper operation (no leaks), and caulk the spout base to the wall with silicone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will have to do is remove the round piece that is shown in your photo. I believe it was an integral piece from the spout. The small thin O-ring that you see on the most forward section should be pressed into the tub spout for a pressure fit. Since that is what keeps it connected to the spout (as opposed to being mechanically secured) it most likely (and easily) loosened as you were repairing the spout. If you use a pipe wrench or a pair of channel lock wrenches (protect the pipe with a rag wrapped around it) it should unscrew counter clockwise. With some luck you will have removed only the spouts base and not the 1/2" pipe nipple inside the wall (you should be able to see the threads inside the wall). Re-connect the spouts base by pressing the two pieces together. Apply Teflon paste to the female threads on the bottom at tighten back in place. What is causing the water to leak is most likely: 1)the valve handle is not exactly in the off position , 2) the washers or valve cartridge needs replacing, 3) the water may not be a leak , but residual water that remains in the pipe after the valve is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I managed to find the product information for the tub spout model I have and see what you mean now.  http://cdn08.grohe.com/lib/1/tpi/696965.pdf
So it sounds like I need to unscrew the part that's sticking out from the wall and attach it to the spout before screwing the entire thing back on.

Comment: I might've been unclear about the "leak" I described in the initial post.  The water comes out of both ends only when the valve handle on (but diverter is set to spout).  There are no leaks when the water is off.  Does this sound like a cartridge issue?

Comment: I don't think it is the valve. Your first answer regarding the diverter on the spout is most likely why water is not flowing to only the shower head when the diverter valve is open, but leaks from the spout also. There is usually a rubber washer that seals the spout opening so that water can not flow through it when the knob is pulled up. This is most likely the cause for the leak. It is much simpler to purchase a new spout ,but if the original is of higher quality materials (brass, chrome, stainless steel) than repairing the damaged washer is also worth the time.

Comment: And to reply to your first comment, yes ,if the spout doesn't fit back onto the base (when the base is secured to the pipe in the wall) remove the base and re-attach it. Apply tape and/or paste (Teflon) and tighten securely.

Comment: I went to the link you posted. Purchase the Grohe part #45617. Also you will need a hex wrench to remove the base. Very well made and quality spout. I have ordered parts for Grohe faucets at: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_5_5?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=grohe+replacement+parts&sprefix=grohe%2Caps%2C243

Comment: Hm, the issue I'm describing is that the water is supposed to only flow through the spout (diverter knob is down), but for whatever reason water is also flowing up to the shower head.
I understand the reverse issue (knob is up, but water leaks from spout) that you describe, but I don't think I have that problem.  And again, thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is still with the washer in the diverter not closing properly. The pdf diagram shows what parts are available for replacement. The part you will need is #45-617.

Comment: I see. I'm going to give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Also note that the pdf diagram shows a set screw on the underside of the spout. This is what will secure the base to the spout before it is re-installed. You will need a 4mm hex wrench to loosen and then tighten the set screw.

Comment: Right. That's how I got the spout off in the first place :)  OTOH, it's not so clear how to replace part #45617 from the diagram

Comment: If you look closely at the pdf diagram (the second photo) were part # 45816 is shown there is a cap as the first part than the pull tab. The third part is a nut and this is what secures the remaining parts below it. If you can carefully remove the cap or the pull and the cap so as to expose the nut it should be easy to disassemble the rest.